# Wix: read text file while in UI sequence

Tags: csv, wix

Wix 3.11
Currently making an installer for an applcation.

I have a text file (comma separating values) that I want to read and to change UI dynamically during the UI sequence of the installer. The file constantly changes.

The file doesn't exist in the target client machine, and if the file is registered as a Component,  it still is not in the target machine because the file deployment occurs during install sequence after the UI sequence.

I expect three solutions for the situation.

- A. an independent text file separate from msi file.
- B. making properties from the text file csv, (If I can harvest wxs file by
  using Heat or other tools)
- C. using CustomAction(C# library),
  reading the file by StreamReader. (I don't know how to define the
  file path in such situation.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Would it be an option to implement this customizable UI in a (Burn) bundle around the MSI?

Comment: Klaus Gütter. Thank you for your advice.
I'm afraid I don't know enough about Burn Bootstrapper, and just now
I don't need Bootstrapper GUI in the installer. 
It seems that Burn Bootstrapper has no-UI mode: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645142/wix-burn-bootstrapping-x86-and-x64-msis-into-single-no-ui-bootstrapper
I am currently searching easy to understand samples for it.

Comment: Burn supports quiet installation using the -q command line flag.